# Magento: remove requirement for Telefone field

Tags: magento

Who can help with removing requirement for Telefone field?

I tried solutions:

http://www.magentocommerce.com/boards/viewthread/10948/P0/

http://www.magentocommerce.com/boards/viewthread/199287/

but without luck...

P.S. I use Magento ver. 1.7.0.2

Answer (score 0):

Try

In your DB table Name : eav_attribute

look for `attribute_code` = telephone

set `is_required` = 0

You may also be able to accomplish this by creating a custom module that extend `Mage_Customer_Model_Form`

```
<customer>
     <rewrite>
          <form>MageIgniter_RemoveRequiredField_Model_Customer_Form</form>
      </rewrite>
</customer>

class MageIgniter_RemoveRequiredField_Model_Customer_Form extends Mage_Customer_Model_Form {

    protected function _getFormAttributeCollection() {

        $collection = parent::_getFormAttributeCollection()
                        ->addFieldToFilter('attribute_code', array('neq' => 'created_at'));
        // look for the 'telephone' field here and change 'is_required'
```